# Slack CURL reminders.app getting internal_error

Tags: slack-api

Trying to use the `reminders.app` to post reminders via curl.

Getting the following error

> {"ok":false,"error":"internal_error","warning":"missing_charset","response_metadata":{"warnings":["missing_charset"]}}

```
curl -X POST -H 'Authorization: Bearer secretsxxxxxxxxxxxxx' -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data \
'{
    "ok": true,
    "reminder": {
        "text": "eat a banana",
        "recurring": false,
        "time": 1602288000
    }
}' https://slack.com/api/reminders.add
```

Comment: When I do that, I get zsh: no matches found: slack.com/api/reminders.add? I tried to escape the ? but then I get the error I got before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the following line `https://slack.com/api/reminders.add` to `https://slack.com/api/reminders.add?`. Include the question mark at the end.

So your code should be:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Authorization: Bearer secretsxxxxxxxxxxxxx' \
-H "Content-type: application/json" \
--data '{"text": "I hope you eat your banana","time":1581447960}' \
https://slack.com/api/reminders.add
```

Comment: When I do that, I get zsh: no matches found: https://slack.com/api/reminders.add?

I tried to escape the ? but then I get the error I got before.

Comment: Your simplified JSON seems to have worked. You don't need to add the ? at the end. Thanks again!